# Supremum proof simple

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

I got stuck on this problem and can't figure it out, I hope somebody can help me, I also wrote my attempt. Thanks in advance!!

> Question: Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. $a_n
>  \to a^*$. Let $A=\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I have to show that:
>   $\sup A  \geq a^*$

My attempt:

Suppose $a_n \in A$.

$a_n$ is bounded because it is convergent. Because $A=\{a_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ we can say that $\forall a_n \in A$ : $a_n \leq \sup A$.

We also know that $a_n \leq a^*$, because it's the limit.

Comment: You can't say that $a_n\leq \sup A$. You would be allowed to say it if you knew that $a_n$ was increasing, but apparently $a_n$ could be something like $\left(-1\right)^n\cdot\frac 1n$. In this case, $a^*=0$, and $a_{2n}>a^*$.

Comment: Is it then maybe usefull to try proof by contradiction?

Comment: @fonini Actually, you *can* say that $a_n\leq \sup A$, since $\sup A$ is by definition an upper bound of $A$, and $a_n$ is an element of $A$. What you **cannot** say is $a_n\leq a^*$, where $a^*$ is the limit of $a_n$.

Comment: $a_n\leq a^*$ is not always true. It's false for a decreasing converging sequence, for example.

Comment: Also, hint: Suppose $u_n\leq v_n$ converging respectively to $u$ and $v$. What can we say about $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b$ be an upper bound for $A$.
Then $a_n \le b$ for all $n$, and so $\displaystyle a^*=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\le b$.

Since $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $A$, we can take $b=\sup A$ and conclude that $a^* \le \sup A$.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comment, proof by contradiction is a good strategy here.

let me denote $a^{*}=a$.

Suppose for a contradiction that $a>\sup A$. Then you knw that $\varepsilon = a-\sup A>0$. This means:

By condition that $a_n\to a$, there exists some $N$ such that for $n \ge N$, $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon=a-\sup A$

Can you see why above gives a contradiction?

Edit: Also, as many others pointed out $a_n\le a^{*}$ is not generally true, it is true if $a_n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

As observed and verified multiple times, $a_n\le \sup A$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Since inequalities stay valid under the limit (making it non-strict if necessary), this directly implies
$$
a_*=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\le \sup A
$$
No epsilontic required.

Comment: But why? $a^*$ does not have to be in A, so how could you jump to this conclusion?

Comment: At this point, $\sup A$ is just a number with a complicated name. The result is equivalent to the statement that a non-negative sequence, if convergent, has a non-negative limit.

Answer (score 0):

We do not know that $a_n\leq a^*$. For example, $\frac1n\leq 0$ is not true, even though $0$ is the limit of $\frac1n$.

Remember, $\sup A$ is defined as **the smallest upper bound for $A$**. This means you need to prove that

- $\sup A$ exists (i.e., $A$ is bounded)
- For every $\epsilon > 0$, $A^*-\epsilon$ is **not** the supremum.

Comment: I am trying really hard, but all I could think of was: $sup A$ exists because a_n is convergent, so it is bounded. I have to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $a^* - \epsilon$ is not the supremum. So suppose $a^*-\epsilon$ is an upperbound for A, then I must find a $a_n \in A$ such that $a_n > a^*-\epsilon$. But I could not find such epsilon ..

Comment: @DeLorean You don't **find** such an $\epsilon.$ You prove by contradiction. You say "Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, this thing is true. Therefore, this other thing is true. Therefore, $a^*-\epsilon$ is not the supremum."

Comment: I meant that I couldnt find such $a_n$, sorry

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that the supremum exists so I'll leave that for you to show (you've pretty much done it anyway).

Now suppose by way of contradiction that $supA<a^{*}$.

Then $\exists  \epsilon_{0}>0$ such that $|a_{n}-a^{*}|\geq\epsilon_{0}\, \forall n \in N$ (follows almost directly from the definition of the supremum). This contradicts the fact that the sequence converges to $a^{*}$ (you should show this using the definition of convergence).

Answer (score 0):

If  $a^*:=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ were strictly larger than $\sigma:=\sup A$ there would be an $a_n>\sigma$, hence $\sigma$ would not be an upper bound of $A$.